# Will nested virtualised machine be avilable for all the users of a windows server

Tags: windows, virtualization, azure

I want to create a Windows Server VM in Azure Cloud and enable nested virtualization and then install another operating system in it.  After that I want to create multiple user accounts on that server. Will those users be able to use nested virtualized machine concurrently?

Comment: If you are going to create a domain and create users there, the users will be able to login in VM which also joined to the domain. Local users of hypervisor will not work, but you can create multiple local users within virtual machine